# how to display images in datalist as per condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I would like to change the displayed image in a DataList as per values retrieved from database.
**Scenario**: I have 5 priorities in my table and as per Priority I need show the image in datalist.

For example

Priority = 5 (Red image)
Priority = 1 (Green image)

How would I show those images as per priority in datalist?

Comment: Please put your code here.. that you have tried with.

Comment: i am new to this Datalist . please help how to do this... iam in very urgent please try to help me with sample code

Answer (score 1):

Set a helper function in the Datalist. Sample code

```
<asp:Image ID="PriorityImage" runat="server" 
         ImageURL='<%# SetPriorityImage(Eval("Priority"))%>'/>
```

AT code behind (aspx.cs)

```
protected string SetPriorityImage(object priority)
{
    string image = "";
    int prioritySwitch = Convert.ToInt32(priority);
    switch (prioritySwitch )
    {
        case 1: 
            image="~/Images/Red.png";
            break;
        case 5:
            image="~/Images/Green.png";
            break;
        default:
            image="~/Images/Error.png";
            break;
    }
    return image;
}
```

Disclaimer: This is just pseudo code and so no try catch mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

You can do on `ItemDataBound` event of datalist.

```
protected void datalist1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {

// Your code logic comes here. here you can find image object that you have used in //ItemTemplate

        }
    }
```

Hope you can do rest of work here.

Comment: Iam just new to this Datalist control please help what should i write ..with some code snippet  that very helpfull to +me